# Is PPO good for episodic delayed reward problems

Tags: reinforcement-learning

The problem I have is episodic (with early stopping when agent reaches goal state or avoid state) and with delayed rewards (agent is rewarded +1 when goal state is reached and penalized -1 when avoid state state is reached). State space is continuous while action space is discrete. I found that DQN/DDQN/averaged DQN learn well (after I shape rewards with potential based function agent reaches goal state the first time in 200 episodes). However, the PPO-clip performance as in https://github.com/ChintanTrivedi/rl-bot-football learning is very slow (agent reaches goal state first time in 3000 episodes). Is it possible somehow to tune PPO-clip for episodic with early stopping and delayed rewards problems?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very late response but others may find the discussion helpful, so I will explain some points:

1. The PPO agent needs a powerful neural net for learning, designing a powerful but not too deep neural net, may limit the learning or convergence time while preserving the excellent accuracy or reward. So, the designed ANN(core or actor and critic) may be carefully designed. Careful in the use of activation functions specially in inner layers, those activation can help you preserve non-linearity!
2. Using a discrete action space for a continuous state space may be tricky! You should carefully map the actions to the environment mechanics. Actually, it may need some creativity based on how your actions may work, but choosing a continuous action space with higher dimensions may help you and ease the problem.
3. The clipping function is not directly related to the convergence episode, it is more related to controlling the size of the steps.
4. If you want to control the parameters to achieve the goal sooner, you have to carefully choose the other parameters like the rate for exploration-exploitation which is usually gamma.
5. GAE may help you, use it!
6. Strategy of using experience replay and vectorized environments can help you a lot. If you are using memory replay you can simulate or repeat some more usual states, or set higher ranks for the extreme states in order to choose those extreme points often in order to learn and handle them.
   Hope it helped!